# Environment Variables are not showing up in my Context component, on Nextjs. Would I need to configure Nextjs? Or set up Context to use the variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Environment Variables are working on every component inside /pages but not in my Context component, in Nextjs. I'm wondering would Nextjs need some configuration?

(Note: Shopcontext.tsx is using a class component, that I got from a tutorial and I'm not familiar enough with context api to change it to a functional component. I tried.)

```
/* Below Shopcontext.tsx */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import Client from "shopify-buy";

const ShopContext = React.createContext({});

const client = Client.buildClient({
  domain: "benson-bracelets.myshopify.com",
  storefrontAccessToken: process.env.SHOPIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN as string,
});

interface State {
  product: {};
  products: Array<any>;
  checkout: any;
}

export class ShopProvider extends Component {
  state: State = {
    product: {},
    products: [],
    checkout: {},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.checkout_id) {
      this.fetchCheckout(localStorage.checkout_id);
    } else {
      this.createCheckout();
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Local storage will hold the  checkoutid.
   *  Shopify will handle the check eachtime a checkout is started.
   * @memberOf ShopProvider
   */
  createCheckout = async () => {
    const checkout = await client.checkout.create();
    localStorage.setItem("checkout_id", checkout.id as any);
    this.setState({ checkout: checkout });
  };

  fetchCheckout = (checkoutId: any) => {
    client.checkout
      .fetch(checkoutId)
      .then((checkout) => {
        this.setState({ checkout: checkout });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error Message, in ShopContext fetchCheckout: ", err);
      });
  };

  fetchAllProducts = async () => {
    await client.product.fetchAll().then((products) => {
      this.setState({ products });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ShopContext.Provider
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          fetchAllProducts: this.fetchAllProducts,
          fetchCheckout: this.fetchCheckout,
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </ShopContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

const ShopConsumer = ShopContext.Consumer;

export { ShopConsumer, ShopContext };

export default ShopProvider;


/* .env file below */

SHOPIFY_DOMAIN=MY_DOMAIN_WOULD_BE_HERE
SHOPIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN=MY_API_WOULD_BE_HERE
```

/* _app.tsx below */

```
import React from "react";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Theme from "../src/ui/Theme";

import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import ShopContext from "../src/context/ShopContext";
import { wrapper } from "../src/store/store";

function MyApp(props: AppProps) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
        <ShopContext>
          <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
            <Component
              {...pageProps}
              {...props}
            />
          </AnimatePresence>
        </ShopContext>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Comment: Did you create the ``next.config.js``` file?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add on to @Mohammad Shaban's answer.

Ever since NextJS 9.4 there is support for loading environment variables through **.env.local** file .

By default all environment variables loaded through .env.local are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser.

In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_. For example:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID=abcdefghijk
```

So don't forget to prefix the env variables with **NEXT_PUBLIC_** in case you are using them in browser.

For more information you can check [this link](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You should define your environment variable inside the `next.config.js` at the route of your project then you will get the env variable in every component

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    customKey: 'my-value',
  },
}
```

it is clearly mentioned in the nextjs document that `Trying to destructure process.env variables won't work due to the nature of webpack`

For more detail please visit the below link

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables